# R: How can I convert a vector of dates to the interval between these dates?

Tags: r

I have a series of dates (they are class Dates) that represent dates someone did something:

```
    mytimes = as.Date(c("2014-08-15", "2014-08-29", "2014-08-01", "2014-09-19", "2014-10-31"))
```

How can I turn calculate the times between these dates and then also calculate the median time between the dates?

I can calculate, for example, the days after the earliest date:

```
    > sort(mytimes) - min(mytimes)
    Time differences in days
    [1]  0 14 28 49 91
```

But I want to get the intervals: 0 14 14 21 42

I have a data.frame where I have multiple users/people that have an entry for every time they logged into a system. I want to summarize the intervals between log-ins. I am hoping there is some nice way to do this... I can just calc the mean time by calculating the total time and dividing my the number of entries, but I want the actual distribution, median, etc. as well. Ideally, something that I could use with dplyr to summarize the data grouped by user.

Edit: I have just discovered lag

Therefore, I can do something like:

```
   dataset <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)), times = rep(mytimes, 2))

    dataset %>% 
     arrange(ID, times) %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     mutate(diff_shift = times - lag(times))


# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
      ID times      diff_shift
   <dbl> <date>     <time>    
 1  1.00 2014-08-01 <NA>      
 2  1.00 2014-08-15 14        
 3  1.00 2014-08-29 14        
 4  1.00 2014-09-19 21        
 5  1.00 2014-10-31 42        
 6  2.00 2014-08-01 <NA>      
 7  2.00 2014-08-15 14        
 8  2.00 2014-08-29 14        
 9  2.00 2014-09-19 21        
10  2.00 2014-10-31 42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can do it like below, based on your example data.

But you need to be aware that depending on how your data.frame looks like, you will need to add a `group_by` of userid's or more variables.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(mytimes = as.Date(c("2014-08-15", "2014-08-29", "2014-08-01", "2014-09-19", "2014-10-31")))
df %>% 
  # group_by(???)
  arrange(mytimes) %>% 
  mutate(time_diff = mytimes - lag(mytimes))

  mytimes    time_diff
  <date>     <time>   
1 2014-08-01 NA       
2 2014-08-15 14       
3 2014-08-29 14       
4 2014-09-19 21       
5 2014-10-31 42
```

Comment: Thanks! I just discovered this independently while writing this. Very helpful!!

Comment: you're welcome. If it helps, you can accept the answer. It will help building your reputation on SO

Answer (score 1):

The base R answer is just

```
> diff(sort(mytimes))
Time differences in days
[1] 14 14 21 42
> median(diff(sort(mytimes)))
Time difference of 17.5 days
```

You may want to add a 0 in at the start, depending on what you're doing.